# How to pass a custom struct from vertex shader to fragment shader

Tags: opengl, struct, glsl, shader

In the fragment shader, I defined two structures as follows

```cpp
struct DirLight{
    vec3 direction;
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
};

struct PointLight {
    vec3 position;
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
    float constant;
    float linear; 
    float quadratic;
};
```

and in vertex shader, I defined the following variables, **because I first want to do some transformations (like matrix multiplication that is not recommended in the fragment shader) on these uniform variables in the vertex shader.**

```cpp
uniform DirLight dirLight; // only one directional light
uniform int pointLightCnt; // number of point light sources
uniform PointLight pointLight[MAX]; // point lights
```

What should I do to transfer the structure in the vertex shader to the fragment shader?

Can I use **a method similar to c++** like:
Define the structure in the **header file**, **include them** in both the **vertex shader** and the **fragment shader**, then define the corresponding `out` variable in the **vertex shader**, and define the corresponding `in` variable in the **fragment shader** to achieve it?

Comment: If they're uniforms (and therefore every vertex gets the same value), why would the need to be "transferred"? Why not just have the fragment shader define the same uniforms?

Comment: @NicolBolas At first I did use uniform in the fragment shader, but I want to do some preprocessing in the vertex shader, such as using a matrix to transform the points, which is not recommended in the fragment shader

Comment: Unless those matrices you want to use to do a transformation are not uniforms *themselves*, an expression where all terms are uniforms is itself a uniform. So just do the computation once on the CPU and pass the data as a uniform.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thank you very much for your help, but as you said, what gives me a headache is that the matrix I used to transform the point is constructed by the parameters specified by the layout in the vertex shader, it is not a fixed transformation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to go into a long explanation of how to implement your lighting structure so it is generic to any light type, but that is a separate issue.

Your current issue is that the Vertex Function shouldn't need to use the lighting uniform at all; there's no data to pass between them. The only thing the Vertex shader should be doing is converting the local space to clip space and saving the intermediate world space as a separate part of the fragment shader's input so it can calculate the lighting properly.

All the lighting calculations can be done on the pixel/fragment shader and any dynamic lighting (positions, penumbra calculations, direction changes, etc) should be done on the CPU and just passed on to the GPU in the lighting buffer/uniform all at once.

This is in hlsl, but it's easily converted to glsl:

```
//Uniform
cbuffer matrix_cb : register(b0) {
    float4x4 g_MODEL;
    float4x4 g_VIEW;
    float4x4 g_PROJECTION;
};

struct vs_in_t {
    float3 position : POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
    float2 uv : UV;
    float4 normal : NORMAL;
};

struct ps_in_t {
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
    float2 uv : UV;
    float4 normal : NORMAL;
    float3 world_position : WORLD;
};

ps_in_t VertexFunction(vs_in_t input_vertex) {
    ps_in_t output;

    float4 local = float4(input_vertex.position, 1.0f);
    float4 normal = input_vertex.normal;
    float4 world = mul(local, g_MODEL);
    float4 view = mul(world, g_VIEW);
    float4 clip = mul(view, g_PROJECTION);

    output.position = clip;
    output.color = input_vertex.color;
    output.uv = input_vertex.uv;
    output.normal = normal;
    output.world_position = world.xyz;

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, and I just started learning opengl on learnopengl, the current headache for me is that the lighting needs to be calculated in tangent space, and the position of my point light source and the direction of the directional light are defined in world space, So I have to transform them into the tangent space first, and then pass them to the fragment shader to calculate the lighting just like [this tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Parallax-Mapping) said

Comment: Okay, I got it. I should use the interface block in glsl to do it, thank you very much

Comment: I have the same problem and I don't know how I would use interface blocks. Could you share your solution ?